# How to get Android LinearLayoutManager to show partial items

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create a layout that looks like this:

[image]

And I haven't been able to find any examples where more than one card is visible at a time.  I'd like the targeted card to SNAP to the center.  Can someone please show me the secret?

Comment: With a `RecyclerView` if the three items don't fit in the screen you will see something like that

Comment: https://github.com/alibaba/UltraViewPager

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39560767/how-to-create-horizontal-scroll-able-cardview

Comment: there are many solutions for this available with `VIewPager`. But if you want this to be done in `RecyclerView` only, let me search it for you. I think it is possible with `RecyclerView.ItemDecoration`.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40584948/how-to-achieve-partially-visible-next-item-in-recyclerview/55242690#55242690

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/viewpagercards), helped decipher the problem. The trick is this view property called

```
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

That and a larger margin than I was expecting.  A margin of 10-20dp was not large enough to see the other views in the list, because of the space between the recyclerview items.  Once I increased the left and right margin to 80dp I got the effect I was looking for.

Answer (score -1):

I think if you're going to achieve that effect, user `LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL` Cannot be realized ，use `viewpager` can realized,I have done a similar effect one year ago,Hope help you